Get current stack offset in solana program
As the title says, how can I log what the current stack offset is during program execution? I found solana_program::instruction::get_stack_height but this seems to be for measuring how deeply nested of a function we're in. I'm referring to measuring how many bytes of data are currently on the stack.

It's a bit tricky, but there's a couple of ways. Let's go through the basics first.

Every stack frame in a Solana program takes up 4096 bytes
The stack address starts at address 0x200000000 according to https://solana.com/fi/docs/programs/faq#memory-map
When a program is compiled, the compiler decides how to lay out stack variables as offsets from the frame pointer.

So if you want to know the current stack offset, you can look at the address of stack variables, which will tell you how many stack frames deep you are, and where in the frame you are. Again, since the compiler can lay things out as it wants, you might need to log the address of all stack variables. You'll also want to watch out for inlining, since the compiler can also combine multiple functions into one.
This simple program was able to print everything out as expected for me:
use solana_program::log::sol_log_64;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn entrypoint(input: *mut u8) -> u64 {
    print_frame(0);
    0
}

#[inline(never)]
fn print_frame(i: u64) {
    if i == 62 {
        return; // otherwise we hit the max call depth 
    }
    let var = 10 * i;
    sol_log_64(
        i, // iteration
        std::ptr::addr_of!(i) as u64 & 0x00000fff, // input variable
        std::ptr::addr_of!(var) as u64 & 0x00000fff, // local variable
        (std::ptr::addr_of!(var) as u64 & 0xfffffff000 - 0x200000000) >> 12, // frame number
        0,
    );
    print_frame(i + 1);
}
#[cfg(target_os = "solana")]
#[no_mangle]
fn custom_panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo<'_>) {}
solana_program::custom_heap_default!();

You should see some output like:
[2024-09-05T20:49:17.673644174Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: 0x0, 0xff0, 0xff8, 0x1, 0x00

If we decode those, we'll see that the first run gives a local address of 0xff0 for the input, ie 4080, and 0xff8 for the local var, ie 4088. Since stack grows down from the top, this makes sense.
So if you want to know how much stack you're using, you can just log the local address of the variables! Be sure to use sol_log_64, since the msg! macro adds a lot more stuff.
Bonus:

In a BPF program, the r10 register normally stores the top of the stack, according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.17/bpf/instruction-set.html

I don't thinks this works exactly as expected in BPF though -- sometimes it would point to the stack, sometimes the heap, sometimes none of those. But if you want to play with it, here's a test program:
#![cfg_attr(target_os="solana",feature(asm_experimental_arch, asm_const))]
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};
use std::arch::asm;
solana_program::entrypoint!(process_instruction);

/// Instruction processor
pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let r10: u64;
    unsafe { asm!("{} = r10", out(reg) r10) };
    solana_program::msg!("stack space used: {}", r10 - 0x200000000);
    Ok(())
}

Thanks for the fun question!

Amazing answer, thanks so much!
